# setInterval keeps on running after clearInterval called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, use-effect

This is a snippet of the code:

```js
var interval3 = null;

React.useEffect(() => {
    if(running) {
    if(interval3) clearInterval(interval3);    
    interval3 = setInterval(() => {
         console.log('running')
      }, 1000);}
      else {
        clearInterval(interval3)
      }  
    
}, [running]);
```

I checked the solutions suggested in other posts but none of them is working.

Comment: If you declare a variable in the main body of a functional component, it will get remade every time the component re-renders. If you want a variable to persist between renders, you need to store it in a ref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use state value to track and keep id of interval. Check below for detail.

```js
  const [id, setId] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (running) {
      if (id) return;
      const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('running');
      }, 1000);
      setId(intervalId)
    } else {
      setId(null);
      clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [running, id]);
```